# Best practice for restlet json error and validation message framework

Tags: java, json, validation, restlet

We have a restlet API, which returns error messages in JSON.  We are passing `setStatus(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_BAD_REQUEST);` before generating a JSON response, and if the operation is successful, we are passing back 200 OK.

My question is: Are there any validation and error message creation frameworks in restlet?  More importantly, what are some best practices for passing error message to UI which they can interpret easily?

Example error message :
Status Code: 400 Bad Request

```
{
   "ErrorMessage": "Unable to **: Failed to get **:Failed to connect to *"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no.

You can follow the twitter way
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses

Personally I suggest to omit the error code id.
The message it self is part of the API contract.
It should be short, clear and in valid English.
{"error|message":"User not found"}
The client should translate "User not found".

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look on the Validator class: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/snapshot/jse/api/org/restlet/routing/Validator.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm looking for this one or similar framework 
http://hibernate.org/validator/